# Deploy > Manage Deployments > Edit > New version: Description becomes "Untitled"

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications, ide

Publishing the latest version of my code while retaining the existing WebApp URL works well in Google Apps Script. The command is ***Deploy > Manage Deployments > Edit > New version > Deploy***.

However, I always have to do it twice because it leaves the Description as "Untitled". I then execute ***Deploy > Manage Deployments > Edit > {paste in new description} > Deploy***, leaving the version unchanged while resetting the Description back to the desired string.

Clearly this isn't a major issue, but it would be nice to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should report this as an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B&pli=1).  We are not Google.

Comment: Please follow the instructions of the corresponding help article. If that is not working, as was mentioned by Cooper, report it to Google by following the instrucctions in the Support page. https://developers.google.com/apps-script

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I submitted it on Google's issue tracker.